# Maintaining a Windows Bluetooth Connection

Tags: windows, bluetooth

I'm manufacturing a device that connects to my computer using Bluetooth and then a desktop Java app uses the Bluetooth connection to send serial data to the device which is then displayed.

When I try to connect my device to windows 7 it successfully finds and pairs with it creating a Bluetooth link on a COM port. This link can then be used by a serial prompt (used for testing) or my Java application. It works initially however soon after windows drops the connection and the only way to reconnect is to delete the device within devices and printers and then reconnect.

This seems to be a known problem with windows bluetooth so I decieded to use a third party Bluetooth application. I downloaded and tried  [Toshiba's Bluetooth Stack](http://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/bluetooth/?page=download) and it was able to add a Bluetooth device and keep a stable connection which works great however this only works for Toshiba computers without getting a cracked version.

This device is commercial and can't be sold with cracked versions of software. Has anybody experienced the same problems or not in other operating systems and has any solutions of advice as that would be a tremendous help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good idea/method to use the COM ports generated by Windows, it's not working fine and not reliable in any scenario ; you should use Bluetooth Sockets instead. 
Using Toshiba or Widcomm or BleuSoleil won't help: under Win7, all dongles are now trying to use the Microsoft Stack, not their own implementation.